# Rotating a visible set of elements in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, wpf-animation

This is more for advertising deals to potential customers so there is no human interaction component to this.

Right now I just have the elements bound to an ItemsControl and a storyboard animation loops through. Unfortunately I want to show 4 items at a time, pause on them for 10 seconds, then show the next 4. I could have 5 coupons, I could have 30, so I can't enter anything in statically except that I know my visible width (they will be rotating horizontally) is 1920px.

My current implementation, which displays 1 to 4 then 5 to 8 and loops back to "1" is:

```
        <ItemsControl Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=VisibleDigitalCoupons}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate.Resources>
                        <Storyboard x:Key="RotateDigitalCoupons" BeginTime="0:0:0" Duration="0:0:10" RepeatBehavior="Forever" Completed="RotateDigitalCouponsCompleted">
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(TranslateTransform.X)" Storyboard.TargetName="digitalCouponView">
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:5" Value="0"></EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:10" Value="-1920">
                                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                        <CubicEase EasingMode="EaseInOut"></CubicEase>
                                    </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </DataTemplate.Resources>
                    <views:DigitalCouponView x:Name="digitalCouponView" Margin="40,40,20,20" Height="240" Width="420" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" >
                        <views:DigitalCouponView.RenderTransform>
                            <TransformGroup>
                                <TranslateTransform/>
                            </TransformGroup>
                        </views:DigitalCouponView.RenderTransform>
                    </views:DigitalCouponView>
                    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Window.Loaded">
                            <BeginStoryboard x:Name="RotateDigitalCoupons_BeginStoryboard" Storyboard="{StaticResource RotateDigitalCoupons}"/>
                        </EventTrigger>
                    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
```

Attempts to use the Completed event to fire off a refresh of the "visible coupons" and reuse the animation have met with failure because the animation is on repeatbehavior forever. However, even with that off, I don't get completed event firing, so that's a dead end AFAIK.

Anyone have any ideas or dealt with this before? Is my process flawed somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a Dispatch Timer which contains a state machine which will execute the logic depending on the current state and handle the data driven components of what will be displayed. Within the timer turn on and off the animations as required.

You will need to make the animations more generic of course, but you have the framework which can be leveraged by the timer.

Comment: Well, this answer is a little sparse but it led me in the right direction at least. Thanks!